# Clickable dropdown in Obiee

Tags: oracle11g, report, obiee

*background info:*
OBIEE, Oracle BI answers.

The business asked us to create an dashboard with clickable links as a menu.

So in the dashboard we’ve created a presentation variable with multiple selection, this works as a variable for the report.
In the report we’ve created sections for all the options in the menu that are activated by a condition. The condition report contains a filter that states: the variable from the menu is equal to ‘my filter’. That way it produces a row for the rowcount.
The reports that are show in the section contain clickable links (drill through), that contain parameters as well, to another dashboard page. So this is all working well.

*actual question*

But now...
they’ve requested to create a drop down menu in order to have a ‘shortcut’ to the drill through reports. 
Problem is as far as I know there isn’t a possibility to create a prompt that can link to a report, nor can it pass parameters values.
An other option could be to create a new variable and if that one is activated it redirects the page to the other ‘dashboard page’.
What would guys you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

There are two bit of functionality in OBIEE that will help you here:

1. [*Action Links* & *Action Link Menus*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/actions.htm#BIEUG646)
2. [*Navigate to BI Content* Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10544/actions.htm#BIEUG10129)

The first is the proper way to approach the dropdown menu option, at least from your description of the requirements, in a much cleaner fashion.

The second enables you to pass values from one page to another.